# How to Solve: Could not Attach to Pid :"777" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS Development. I tried to create an app in Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS Simulator (9.3) and Swift.

While executing the app it is showing error like:

> "Could not Attached to Pid:"777"(Unable to Attach).

I have tried to "Resetting the content and settings in the simulator" and "Window > Organizer > Projects > Derived Data", but still I didn't get the solution. Please anyone help me.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: After resetting content and settings, quit the simulator and start it again

Comment: I tried that solution even though it didn't work.Basic Hello World it self is not displaying.please kindly help.

Comment: are you define particular view controller class in storybord?

Comment: I defined like this: 
class ViewController: UIViewController {    
  }

Comment: Are you running xcode from the mounted Xcode volume which is visible on the desktop? I assume not but ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try either of the following

- reset content and settings
- Restart the simulator
- close and restart    the project
- Restart Xcode
- Restart the system

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned in [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120282?page=2), It's an issue with authorization. Try this in the Terminal:

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```